# How to select or deselect all checkboxlist from other CheckBox control in form

Tags: c#, winforms

Problem inside case:

1. If I select all, CheckBox controls:  it works according to logic
2. If I deselect all CheckBox controls: It works according to logic.
3. Problem: when user selects one by one checked box manually , when user check all options manually, below select all checked box will show as checked.
4. Problem: user select all checkboxes in list and deselect any one option form a list,  below select all checked box button will unchecked

Code:

```
if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    int length = chktb.Items.Count;

    for (int le = 0; le < length; le++)
    {

        chktb.SetItemChecked(le, true);
    }
    checkBox1.Checked = true;

}
else 
{
    int length = chktb.Items.Count;

    for (int le = 0; le < length; le++)
    {

        chktb.SetItemChecked(le, false);
    }

    checkBox1.Checked = false;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eSVF.jpg

Comment: I have linked a snapshot to understand.

Comment: Snapshot won't help. Try to rewrite this question cause it's unreadable.

Comment: I understand the code you show is executed when selecting the Select All checkbox. Show us also code that is triggered when you select a single checkbox (not Select All one).

Comment: Select all and deselect all is working , I have put logic in CheckBox Change_event......But the problem is if user select all items manually from a list,another check box contro may be automatically checked .

Comment: @Rahul_ROck, to help us to help you, you need to explain yourself better. Do this: 1. State what you want to accomplish. 2. Show ALL the relevant code. 3. Show what you expect to happen on each different scenario and 4. Explain what is happening on each different scenario pointing, if possible, the problem, in the code.

Comment: Ok sorry i have done it.....thanks for support...

Comment: At least put your answer here. :)

Comment: I write code below ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            int length = chktb.Items.Count;

            for (int le = 0; le < length; le++)
            {
                chktb.SetSelected(le, true);
                chktb.SetItemChecked(le, true);
            }
            checkBox1.Checked = true;

        }



        else 
        {
            int length = chktb.Items.Count;

            for (int le = 0; le < length; le++)
            {
                chktb.SetSelected(le, false);
                chktb.SetItemChecked(le, false);
            }

            checkBox1.Checked = false;

        }




    }
```

private void checklistBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        int length=chktb.Items.Count; 

        int check_count=chktb.CheckedItems.Count;  //total checked box in list

        if (length == chktb.CheckedItems.Count)
        {

            checkBox1.Checked = true;

        }

    }
```